# Availability Group how to determine last Failover time

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, availability-groups

I'd just like to know if there is any way to query when the AG group failed over.

eg - this is the Primary Replica now, but I'm pretty sure it was the secondary yesterday?  How can i find when the failover took place

is there something specific in the Logs I should be looking for, or is there a tsql script to use?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use following PowerShell script to get last failover time

```
Get-winEvent -ComputerName ListnerName -filterHashTable @{logname ='Microsoft-Windows-FailoverClustering/Operational'; id=1641}| ft -AutoSize -Wrap
```

1641 is the event ID within the Windows event logging system that indicates that a clustered role has moved from one node to another. The id=1641 part causes the Get-WinEvent command to filter for only those events.

Comment: Works great. But as @Trubs pointed out - not working (or working very slow) when running from local pc, but using `etsn ListenerName` and running command there (without `ComputerName` parameter ofc) works great. I've added reverse sort (cause I'm that lazy for scrolling) and it's looks like this: `Get-WinEvent -filterHashTable @{logname ='Microsoft-Windows-FailoverClustering/Operational'; id=1641}| sort TimeCreated | ft -AutoSize -`

Answer (score 15):

Following lists failover time and direction for each database for all failover events on the server on which this is run, using T-SQL as requested.

```
-- Script to determine failover times in Availability Group 

;WITH cte_HADR AS (SELECT object_name, CONVERT(XML, event_data) AS data
FROM sys.fn_xe_file_target_read_file('AlwaysOn*.xel', null, null, null)
WHERE object_name = 'error_reported'
)

SELECT data.value('(/event/@timestamp)[1]','datetime') AS [timestamp],
       data.value('(/event/data[@name=''error_number''])[1]','int') AS [error_number],
       data.value('(/event/data[@name=''message''])[1]','varchar(max)') AS [message]
FROM cte_HADR
WHERE data.value('(/event/data[@name=''error_number''])[1]','int') = 1480
```

Answer (score 7):

Although its difficult to find out when the last fail-over occurred, you can get a notification (alert) when the fail-over does occur...  (you can then search your email?)

You can create an alert to let you (or your team) know when a fail-over occurred using Error Number 1480

[image: 1]]

Note:  This will send an email for every database in the AG (on each server), which in my case was 12 databases on 2 servers.   On the options tab you can set `Delay between responses:`  to something like 1 minute, so that only one email a minute is sent.

Comment: The reason I marked my own response as the answer was I wanted something within SQL to take care of this and this is a complete answer (imo). And its very useful to know if you've just failed over... If you come  to SO looking to find historical failovers, after the fact, I think @mashrur answer is the most complete answer

Comment: There are useful directions for setting this up [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3489/configure-sql-server-alerts-and-notifications-for-alwayson-availability-groups/).

Answer (score 4):

You can set up a monitoring script (or a 3rd party SQL monitoring solution), to query the various columns of the **sys.dm_hadr_availability_replica_states** DMV on a regular schedule (e.g. every 30 seconds) and put a timestamp on it of when you've collected the values.

The particular columns of interest related to failover events are:

- last_connect_error_number
- last_connect_error_description
- last_connect_error_timestamp

Additional columns that are worth tracking:

- role
- operational_state
- connected_state

More detailed description for the above columns:

[sys.dm_hadr_availability_replica_states (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878537.aspx)

An overview of all DMVs for AlwaysOn Availability Groups with links to more details is available on MSDN:

[Monitor Availability Groups (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878305.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

If the failover is successful, then windows event logs would have an entry

> The state of the local availability replica in availability group '' has changed from 'RESOLVING_NORMAL' to 'PRIMARY_PENDING'
>
> The state of the local availability replica in availability group '' has changed from 'PRIMARY_PENDING' to 'PRIMARY_NORMAL'

This [MS KB article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2833707) has details about the error message and you can use [PowerShell script](http://www.webofwood.com/2013/10/07/know-group-failover-powershell/) to send you email based on specific events.

Apart from the windows event log, you can look at [Cluster Diagnostic Extended Event Log](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_pfe_blog/archive/2013/04/08/sql-2012-alwayson-availability-groups-automatic-failover-doesn-t-occur-or-does-it-a-look-at-the-logs.aspx) with a format that resembles - `ServerName_InstanceName_SQLDIAG_*.xel`

Answer (score -1):

I added a `select (top(1)`, which is required to make the script in [the other answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/196613) work:

```
declare @PrimaryServer varchar(50),
        @SecondaryServer varchar(50)

set @SecondaryServer = (select top(1) ar.replica_server_name
                from master.sys.availability_replicas ar
                join master.sys.dm_hadr_availability_replica_states ars
                on ar.replica_id = ars.replica_id
                where role_desc = 'SECONDARY')

set @PrimaryServer = (select top(1) ar.replica_server_name
                from master.sys.availability_replicas ar
                join master.sys.dm_hadr_availability_replica_states ars
                on ar.replica_id = ars.replica_id
                where role_desc = 'PRIMARY')
select @@SERVERNAME as Servername, @PrimaryServer as PrimaryServer,  @SecondaryServer as SecondayServer

--If this is the secondary server, do whatever
If  @@SERVERNAME = @SecondaryServer 
    begin
        select @@SERVERNAME as Servername,  @SecondaryServer as SecondayServer
    end
Else
    begin
       select @@SERVERNAME as Servername, @PrimaryServer as PrimaryServer
    end
```

Comment: That doesn't answer when a failover had happened, right?

Answer (score -3):

This the code I use to determine which server is the Primary node and which one is the secondary node.  I use this in every job on my server.

**NOTE: this is for a 2-node AOAG.  Adjust it as needed to handle multiple-server AOAGs.**

```
declare @PrimaryServer varchar(50),
        @SecondaryServer varchar(50)

set @SecondaryServer = (select ar.replica_server_name
                from master.sys.availability_replicas ar
                join master.sys.dm_hadr_availability_replica_states ars
                on ar.replica_id = ars.replica_id
                where role_desc = 'SECONDARY')

set @PrimaryServer = (select ar.replica_server_name
                from master.sys.availability_replicas ar
                join master.sys.dm_hadr_availability_replica_states ars
                on ar.replica_id = ars.replica_id
                where role_desc = 'PRIMARY')

--If this is the secondary server, do whatever
If @@SERVERNAME = @SecondaryServer 
    begin
        --Put your code here for Secondary Server actions
    end
Else
    begin
        --Put code here for Primary Server actions
    end

--End If
```