# Why did the last Availability Group failover occur?

Tags: sql-server-2016, availability-groups

My SQL Server 2016 Availability Group failed over to the secondary node within the cluster. I'm not sure when this happened and to save time trawling back through the logs: Is there a quick and easy way to check when & why the last failover occurred?

Comment: Have a look at [This MSDN thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/89a2944e-57fd-49f3-9d66-8b3b31e36bf2/sql-server-2014-always-on-find-out-when-the-last-failover-occurred?forum=sqldatabaseengine)

Comment: also its asked before https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/131634/availability-group-how-to-determine-last-failover-time